# How to do a select with ASC NULLS FIRST in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a `ASC NULLS FIRST` in Sequelize with NodeJS and MariaDB. This is my code:

```
return res.json(await Games.findAll({
                where: {
                    is_finished: 0,
                    is_private_game: 0
                },
                order: [
                    ['player_two_username', 'ASC NULLS FIRST']
                ]
            }));
```

However, I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

```
original: SqlError: (conn=119, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULLS FIRST' at line 1
```

The query is

```
SELECT `game_id`, `player_one_username`, `player_two_username`, `is_finished`, `is_private_game`, `matrix_id`, `deletedAt`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Games` AS `Games` WHERE (`Games`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND (`Games`.`is_finished` = 0 AND `Games`.`is_private_game` = 0)) ORDER BY `Games`.`player_two_username` ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 5;
```

I also tried

```
return res.json(await Games.findAll({
                where: {
                    is_finished: 0,
                    is_private_game: 0
                },
                order: [
                    Sequelize.fn('isnull', Sequelize.col('player_two_username')),
                    ['player_two_username', 'ASC']
                ],
                limit: AMOUNT_ROOMS_ROOMLIST
            }));
```

But it didn't work either.

The query is

```
SELECT `game_id`, `player_one_username`, `player_two_username`, `is_finished`, `is_private_game`, `matrix_id`, `deletedAt`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Games` AS `Games` WHERE (`Games`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND (`Games`.`is_finished` = 0 AND `Games`.`is_private_game` = 0)) ORDER BY isnull(`player_two_username`), `Games`.`player_two_username` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What query it is generating ?

Comment: What DB are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I could do it.

```
return res.json(await Games.findAll({
                where: {
                    is_finished: 0,
                    is_private_game: 0
                },
                order: [
                    [Sequelize.fn('isnull', Sequelize.col('player_two_username')), 'DESC']
                ],
                limit: AMOUNT_ROOMS_ROOMLIST
            }));
```

It's generating this query

```
SELECT `game_id`, `player_one_username`, `player_two_username`, `is_finished`, `is_private_game`, `matrix_id`, `deletedAt`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Games` AS `Games` WHERE (`Games`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND (`Games`.`is_finished` = 0 AND `Games`.`is_private_game` = 0)) ORDER BY isnull(`player_two_username`) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This way, it will be order by isnull is desc order (null first)